# Some Text of Application name displaying in next line

Tags: android, android-layout

Some part of Application name is displaying in next line under logo on Home Screen.
For example :- "RockingApps" is my application name. But "s" of RockingApps is displaying in next line on few devices.
And I have not found any property in Manifest file to restrict APPLICATION NAME/LABEL.

Answer (score 1):

Different devices have different density's and screen sizes so depending on the device if the title is to long it will overflow to the next line. Setting the app title "Rocking Apps" with the space i believe will add a line break at the space if the title is to long for one line.

Comment: +1 Another thing that is uncontrollable in this regard is devices that have custom launchers that allow the user to change the number of application icons either vertically or horizontally, this will also give undesired and uncontrollable results in the name text wrapping. There is simply nothing that can be done, other then trying to utilize the space by changing to an abbreviation, or in this case creating a space between words.